# How to shuffle/randomize list items after regrouping them using Django's regroup template tag

Tags: python, django

I have this list presented in dictionaries:

```
cities = [
    {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
    {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
    {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
]
```

I have regrouped the list using Django's regroup tag:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is the template output:

```
India
Mumbai: 19,000,000
Calcutta: 15,000,000

USA
New York: 20,000,000
Chicago: 7,000,000

Japan
Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

That is pretty much of what I intended to do. I now want to randomly shuffle items under each country list. For example, under USA, I want to shuffle New York and Chicago so that the display is not biased to the viewer. When I use `shuffle(cities)` in my views, I get an output like this:

```
India
Mumbai: 19,000,000

USA
New York: 20,000,000

India
Calcutta: 15,000,000

USA
Chicago: 7,000,000

Japan
Tokyo: 33,000,000
```

I basically want to shuffle cities while remaining intact under their countries. I dont want the order of countries to change but only the order of cities to change randomly. I am stuck on what to do from here. I tried a custom template simple_tag but still things didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> cities = [
     {'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
     {'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
     {'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
     {'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
     {'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'},
 ]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(cities)
>>> print(cities)
[{'name': 'Mumbai', 'population': '19,000,000', 'country': 'India'},
{'name': 'Tokyo', 'population': '33,000,000', 'country': 'Japan'}, 
{'name': 'New York', 'population': '20,000,000', 'country': 'USA'},
{'name': 'Chicago', 'population': '7,000,000', 'country': 'USA'}, 
{'name': 'Calcutta', 'population': '15,000,000', 'country': 'India'}]
```

So, before rendering data into template shuffle list there.

```
import random
random.shuffle(cities)
```

**Don't use the code of the upper part.**

But it will change your country's order. So you can use custom template tag for shuffle.

Firstly create a folder named templatetags. then create a file name `__init__.py`. it would be empty. and create another file named `shuffle.py`. there save the bellow code.

```
# YourApp/templatetags/shuffle.py
import random
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def shuffle(arg):
    tmp = list(arg)[:]
    random.shuffle(tmp)
    return tmp
```

Project Directory:

```
-Your_App
--templatetags
---__init__.py
---shuffle.py
```

Now in your template:

```
{% regroup cities by country as country_list %}

<ul>
{% for country in country_list %}
    <li>{{ country.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for city in country.list|shuffle %}
          <li>{{ city.name }}: {{ city.population }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```