# shuffle HTML list element order - django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to shuffle list when the user open the page he will see every time different order
for example:

```
<form name = "quiz" action=""  method="post" class="from-inline">
<input name = "incorrect" type="submit" value={{word_1.Hebrew_word}} 
class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input name = "incorrect" type="submit" value={{word_2.Hebrew_word}} 
 class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input name = "incorrect" type="submit" value={{word_3.Hebrew_word}} 
 class="btn btn-primary"/>
<input name = "correct" type="submit" value= 
{{random_word_to_guess.Hebrew_word}} class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

I try to shuffle the input ..

Comment: will these data come from database?

Comment: yes I make quiz with 4 options and every time I want to put the correct answer in different place . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790406/how-to-shuffle-html-field-django

Comment: you can make a custom template register. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: No I'm beginner.. I will look for it no

Comment: Without passing single word separately make a list in view and make a custom register like it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599125/how-to-shuffle-randomize-list-items-after-regrouping-them-using-djangos-regroup/68599164#68599164

Comment: I added my specific code to be more specific .. I try to shuffle the "name" of the input ..